# How to store the one decimal point after calculating the average in javascript

Tags: javascript, decimal, average, cypress

```
 var result = parseFloat(text1) + parseFloat(text2) + parseFloat(text3);
 result = Math.floor(result / 3)
 expect(result.toFixed(1)).to.equal(14.2);

 text1=14.1, text 2=22.3, 6.3
```

Result in cypress

expected `14.0` to `equal 14.2`

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- You should not call `Math.floor` as then you will lose all decimals, and `toFixed(1)` will always just add ".0" to such an integer value.
- Expect a string data type from `toFixed`, not a numerical value

So:

```
result = result / 3; // Don't floor
expect(result.toFixed(1)).to.equal("14.2"); // expect a string.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you apply `result = Math.floor(result / 3)` you got rid of the decimal and get an integer, so use:

```
result = Math.round(10 * result / 3) / 10
```